# What is the best way to provide web-based client-side video compression/conversion?

Tags: java, flash, video, video-processing

I want to create a website for users to upload videos, but I want to do some compression/conversion on the client-side first before actually uploading to my servers. This should cut down on upload times I hope.

My inital thought is to make a Java Applet, since I imagine Flash wouldn't have ffmpeg on the client-side. I'm not sure what version of Java to use, or whether to use Java Web FX. I haven't touched Java in years, so I don't even know what IDE or SDK to use (I'm on a Mac).

Comment: If any of the sides is MP4 compression, I suspect transcoding will take a *LOT* more time than uploading - you should test that first.

Comment: this might be useful: first of three blog posts about restoring quality of low bitrate H.264 video in flash - http://sonnati.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/flash-h-264-h-264-squared/

Comment: Do you assume you can have ffmpeg on the client side? There's no pure Java implementation of it, all use native code...

Comment: well, I naievely assumed that since it's open source it could be ported, but now that seems like a ton of work.

Comment: This question if actually good. Ranks high in search results. Can people please vote to re-open.